# Firebase public user access limiting and protecting against malicious attacks

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to create a single page application where public users can upload photos and anyone who visits the website can like/dislike the photos. I'm using Firebase database and storage.

My question is how can I avoid any malicious activities such as adding images through a script and liking them? Can I throttle access or use a CSRF token? Or is the only way to avoid such an attack is to authenticate the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict uploads to be in the user's key, you have to auth the user. Set up write access to be that user and admin.

Answer (score 2):

You could hash the ip of the client into a lookup table in Firebase itself along with a timestamp, and use a rule or logic in cloud fn to make sure you're not getting hammered from the same place. First choice would not add any cost, but is more limited; second choice would mean that you run a function for each insert but can run more elaborate defences.

Maybe you can do something more useful using Firestore? For all the thing that it's missing, the rule system is more robust.

However, I would suggest that if you have no current or pressing problem with spamming, don't try to solve this first: don't think about painting the shed before building the shed.

Comment: Given it's hard to spoof ip, you suggestion would work. But I was more after a Firebase rules. Couldn't agree more on the garage analogy.